# uninstalling and reinstalling 13.04 to a different hard drive

Tags: installation, partitioning

i recently downloaded and installed ubuntu 13.04, the problem is that i deleted windows operating system by mistake so now only have ubuntu to work off of, im trying to uninstall and reinstall ubuntu to a different hard drive as the one it is currently installed on doesnt have sufficient disk space, could someone instruct how to do this, explaining the partitioning part too as im new and dont fully understand it

Answer (score 0):

Pop up in the CD that has the Ubuntu install, and click Try Ubuntu when it loads. Click Dash (in the top left) and search for GParted. When the application opens up, on the top right, you should see a drop down arrow to scroll between different hard drives. Scroll between all of them, and (assuming you don't have any important data on this computer), delete all of the partitions so you can start fresh. You can do this by highlighting a partition and clicking the X, then the checkmark to verify that you want to delete the partition. Again, **please be sure that the partition doesn't contain anything important before you delete it.**. When this is all done, it should say unformatted or unallocated. After you have erased your previous Ubuntu installation, click Install Ubuntu, and go through those steps. When it reaches the step about where you want to install Ubuntu, do **not** click the Something Else option. Just let Ubuntu do it for you, but make sure you are installing it on a hard drive that does have enough disk space.

Comment: ok, i see all the patitions and "boot" is in the partition that only holds 7.50gb. is it safe to delete that? will ubuntu install the "boot" again? that way i can delete all partitions and start over?

Comment: Yes, please delete all partitions (assuming you don't have any Windows data or anything you would like to keep). After deleting, hit Install Ubuntu and make sure the hard drive you wish to install Ubuntu on is the one you want.